# Como executar uma função depois de um determinado tempo em Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame

Estou fazendo um game com Python, em que personagem pula obstáculos e cai depois de alguns segundos. Em javascript utilizei a função setTimeOut pra isso. Em Python tentei fazer a mesma coisa com time.sleep(), Timer(), set_timer() e loop for. A intenção é que o personagem pule, fique um tempo no ar, e depois caia; mas ao invés disso o programa inteiro pausa (incluindo o movimento do cenário e dos obstáculos).

Trecho do meu código em Python

```
        if(leituradoTeclado.sePegeUpPressionada(event) and iniciarJogo == True):
            personagem.pular()
            time.sleep(5)
            personagem.cair()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode usar o `time.sleep()` pois ele vai parar toda a execução do programa. Ao invés disso, sempre deixe o controle retornar para o seu loop de eventos, e faça tudo o que for fazer através de eventos. Você não pode deixar o programa parar nunca, pois ele sempre tem que ficar redesenhando a tela x vezes por segundo. Então tudo que você for fazer, tem que fazer aos poucos e deixar o loop rodar para continuar.

Uma forma bem limpa de fazer é usar o `pygame.time.set_timer()` que permite você colocar um evento próprio na fila de eventos do pygame, depois de um tempo determinado.

Como você não compartilhou código completo, eu escrevi um exemplo, para pular com a tecla w:

```
def trata_eventos():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
             sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if event.key == pygame.K.w:
                 personagem.pular()
                 # programa o pygame para gerar o evento daqui a 5 segundos
                 pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 5000)
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1: 
             # evento disparou! desabilita o evento:
             pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 0) 
             personagem.cair()

def desenha_tela(): # desenha o quadro atual
    # ... desenha o fundo, e todos os personagens em sua posicao atual ...
    personagem.desenhar() 
    pygame.display.flip() 

while True: # loop principal; cada repetição é um quadro a ser desenhado
    trata_eventos()
    desenha_tela()
    clock.tick(60) # espera para manter 60FPS
```